# Docker Compose WordPress, where are my WordPress files stored

Tags: windows, docker, wordpress

I have successfully setup WordPress following the official instructions on docker's documentation. I am running windows and I can't seem to figure out where I edit my WordPress files such as `wp-content` so on so fourth. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` that I used to setup the container. Thanks ahead of time. Does it have something to do with the `volumes` setting? I shared my `C` drive with docker.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Edit: I would like to have my WordPress files in the same directory that I setup the container which is `C:/Users/andersk/sites/wordpress`.

Comment: The wordpress files will be in the container and database.

Comment: Ok, where is that, how do I traverse into the directory and open it in my code editor? Is there a way to have it be in `C:/Users/andersk/sites/wordpress`

Comment: "where is that" - where you've put it. There is no defualt path for docks. "how do I traverse into the directory" - As said, a container is not a directory, it is a container. "open it in my code editor" - Like on any other (linux?) server. "Is there a way to have it be in ..." - No, not from a closes container. You'd have to install Wordpress on you Windows  for that.

Comment: Actually I found an answer that fixed it for me, see below.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me adding a volumes line pointing towards the folder on my C Drive

```
volumes: 
       - C:/Users/andersk/sites/wordpress-site:/var/www/html
```

See Above for line added

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "3000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     volumes: 
       - C:/Users/andersk/sites/wordpress-site:/var/www/html // This fixed it
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but got an error: ERROR: for wp2_wordpress_1  Cannot create container for service wordpress: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}

Comment: (cont'd) I am logged on a cmd window as admin user, I tried mkdir command directly it works

Comment: here's the wordpress section of the docker-compose file:    wordpress:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: wordpress:latest
        ports:
        - "8001:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
        volumes: 
          - C:/Sites/wp2/volumes:/var/www/html